# Using of System.Security.Permissions.DataProtectionPermissionAttribute

Tags: .net, data-access, code-security

Have you ever used this class in real world application? Can you imagine scenarios where it can be useful? I'm asking because in WCF there is `MessageBodyMemberAttribute` to control data integrity/encryption and wonder if they're somehow related.

Answer (score 2):

Very useful attribute, for example with php client, without this one php did not understand wcf's wsdl.